# Group by count take top 3

Tags: python, pandas

I have a database with source and destination, I would like to apply the group by returning only the top 3 destinations per source.

[image]

**Like this.**

[image]

Comment: Remember always include your sample/expected data as text, not pictures.

Comment: It's better to provide some text than screenshots for pandas related questions

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
s=df.groupby(['Origin','Destinations']).size().sort_values().groupby(level=0).head(3).sort_index(level=0)
```